# Does there exist an example that the image of a valuation $\textrm{Im}(v)\setminus \{0\}$ is not a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory

Consider a multiplicative valuation $v:K \rightarrow \Gamma\cup\{0\}$, where $\Gamma$ is a totally ordered abelian group and $K$ is a field. I saw the definition of its value group in some references, that a value group of a valuation $v$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by $\operatorname{Im}(v)\setminus\{0\}$. However, in other references, the value group is $\operatorname{Im}(v)\setminus\{0\}$. Is there an example where the image of a valuation $\operatorname{Im}(v)\setminus\{0\}$ is not a group? Or the two definitions are in fact the same?

Comment: You need to define what is going on here. What do the terms mean to you, otherwise I'm just able to take the $p$-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Z}$ and the image is $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$...... The image of a function doesn't mean much if you're not specifying the domain and codomain

Comment: @Mummy the turkey: Just consider the multiplicative valuation over a field $K$ $v: K\rightarrow \Gamma\cup\{0\}$, where $\Gamma$ is a totally ordered abelian group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $u \in K$ we have that $v(u) = 0$ if and only if $u = 0$. Then by definition $v$ is a homomorphism taking the group $K^\times = K \setminus \{0\}$ to the group $\Gamma$. By basic group theory, the image is a group.

Comment: Right! If consider the valuation $v$ on a ring $R$, there exists some non-zero $x\in R$ such that $v(x)=0$, then is Im$(v)\setminus\{0\}$ still a group? I think that in this case $v(R^{\times})$ is not a group, but Im$(v)\setminus\{0\}$ is.

Comment: @ToneyLeung The way you have worded the question is so that $v(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$ (to stop this being confusing since $\Gamma$ is normally additive this is usually called $\infty$). Again $v(R^{\times})$ will always be a group (since it is the image of a group) under a group hom. However $v(R)$ may only be a semigroup (my example above with $R = \mathbb{Z}$ for example).